# Right way to call definition for Delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I am using delayed_job for some processes in my application. It is not taking any effect and run the code on the fly. The following is the code.

```
Module1::some_definition(param).delay(priority=>3, :run_at=>2.minutes.from_now)
```

Am i doing it the wrong way?

**UPDATE:**
This is what i have done suggested by dimitko. But still i get error.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def do_something
      #Google is my module and the do_some_process is definition.
      Google.delay.do_some_process
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of `.delay` is to chain it with the real job method you want to call.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def do_something
  # ... do something long which you want to be in the background...
  end
end
```

A "proper" way of delaying this code with `delayed_job` would be:

```
User.current.delay(priority=>3, :run_at=>2.minutes.from_now).do_something
```

I don't think `delayed_job` is intended to inject the `.delay` method in modules as your example code suggests.

Comment: So, u mean dat modules cannot be used with delayed_job.

Comment: I believe so. You are free to check the code here though: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Comment: when tried to test with your code suggestion i received the following error... User#do_something failed with NoMethodError: undefined method `do_something' for #<User:0xcc10988

Comment: In my example `do_something` was a method that **you** should define in your User class, which does the slow job you would like to be done in background. So nothing mystical.

Comment: This doesn't sound right. Could you please update your original post with the code you added to your User model?

Comment: In your User method you must have this: `Google.do_some_process` (without `delay`). And then, when you want to *queue* the job, you do this: `current_user.delay.do_something`. In short, the concept of `delayed_job` is this: you must prepend the `.delay` in front of the method you wish to call asynchronously.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try setting up a Cron job. I usually create a rake task and then run that using a Cron job.

Thanks